# How do you verify that the "CRON JOB" is functioning correctly for a site?

Tags: cron, catalog-price-rules

We are using Magento `1.9.0` and catalog prices rules are disappearing on products list page sometimes.

I suspect that the cronjob is not working on the site.

This is `cron.php` in root of the site : `cron.php` = http://pastebin.com/DP3uG3q0

What do I have to do to verify that the "cron job" is working correctly?

Comment: Did you set the cron to run on your system? http://help.sweettoothrewards.com/article/395-setting-up-cron-jobs-in-magento

Comment: this is what i did for our site : http://i.stack.imgur.com/6hZRn.png

Comment: I'm not referring to the backend. Read the link I posted above

Comment: sorry, i will check that link now.....

Comment: i will downlaod sweet tooth and try....

Comment: is i have to install this : http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/sweet-tooth-loyalty-reward-points.html

Comment: you don't have to install anything. look on the web for ways to enable a cron. you should find a lot of answers.

Comment: okay may  i will follow this : Setting up the Cron In a UNIX Based Operating System in that link....

Comment: may i run following commands :       */5 * * * * /bin/sh /[magento_path]/cron.sh */5 * * * * /bin/bash /[magento_path]/cron.sh    , 
*/5 * * * * /usr/bin/php /[magento_path]/cron.php     ,
*/5 * * * * /usr/local/bin/php -f /[magento_path]/cron.php

Comment: @Marius was just showing you a page on how to set up a cron, you don't need to download their module. If you are not familiar with any server configuration change, I would advise leaving this to someone more competent

Comment: we want to check cron job is working or not, so i installed this extension : https://github.com/AOEpeople/Aoe_Scheduler

its displaying cron job is not working.

so i want to use this : http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/how_to_setup_a_cron_job

they mentioned like this for unix based systems : http://pastebin.com/WXeGVPxJ

we don't have cpanel access, we are using amazon web service and we are using putty ssh.

i am new to these ssh commands.

please inform me what commands i have to run in above link to install cron job succesfully

Comment: @Marius you can post as an answer, i will accept it.

Comment: You can post as an answer what you did and accept it.

Comment: you are ultimate : @Marius

Comment: i can accept in 22 hours, i will acept it......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as refereed by @Marius in the comments, I followed the link he provided : http://help.sweettoothrewards.com/article/395-setting-up-cron-jobs-in-magento
and verified the cron job is functioning by using this extension: http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/aoe-scheduler.html , now cron job is working fine now.

Comment: sr_magento i don't know why you removed that "king of magento " text?